# C: Variable value gets dirty while returning to calling function

Tags: c

Take a look at this code:

```
 extern void f3(int);

 void f2 (int foo) {
     //some stuff
     f3(foo)
     printf("f2:%d\n",foo);
 }
 void f1 (int foo) {
      //some stuff
      f2(foo);
      printf("f1:%d\n",foo);
 }

 int main() {
      //some stuff
      f1(foo)
      //other stuff
      return 0;
 }
```

My problem is that i have outputs like:

```
 f2: 1060 //this is the correct value
 f1: 1065294485
```

There is no code between the print in the function f2 and the end of the function. There is no code between the call of the function f2 and the print in the function f1. How is possible this change of value?
I need to allocate big data structures in the stack and I'm using ulimit -s 2^28. I'm also using gcc -mO0 -m32 -msse to compile because the function f3 is written in nasm with sse. Can the problem depend on this?
Ask me for other things that may be helpful to understand the problem.

Edit: I'm showing the real f2() function:

```
void upgma_start(float* centroids,int k,int c,int d,float* size,float *md) {
     float mc1 [d];
     float mc2 [d];
     upgma(centroids,k,c,d,size,md,mc1,mc2);
     printf("uuu:::%d:\n",k);
}
```

the function upgma is the function f3 of the example code and k is the foo var.

Comment: What exacly does f3 do? Can you replace it with a dummy function and check what the result is?

Comment: The important thing here is where you put // other stuff

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're getting. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @maja: I check the value of foo after the end of f3, so I'm sure that f3 doesn't overwrite the value.

Comment: @fernando.reyes: as I said there are no operations between the print and the end of the function in the function f2, and there are no operations between the call of f2 and the print in the function f1.

Comment: It does not matter what f3() does, foo is passed by value. What is important is what happens to `foo`  in `f2()` before being printed.

Comment: @user3415993 How is foo declared? is it just an int foo?

Comment: @BenjaminT: nothing. The line after the call of f3() is printf(). In f1() the line after the call of f2() is printf(). In f2() there is nothing after the printf()

Comment: @fernando.reyes: yes, is just an int

Comment: @user3415993 Yes, but what happens in f2() before the call to f3() ? If you change foo in f2() before the call to f3()  you will change the value of foo printed in f2(), but not the one printed in f1().

Comment: @user3415993 I think datenwolf has the right answer, follow his instructions and come back with results

Comment: @BenjaminT: the value of foo is never changed, is an input value.

Comment: @user3415993 Anyway, if you want to be sure, try printing `foo`value in `f1()` just before you call `f2()`. If the values in `f1` don't change, it means you changed `foo` in `f2`. If the values in `f1` changes, it means you have messed with your memory (see datenworlf answer).

Comment: Looking at you edit, I hope this are not your actual variable names

Comment: @maya What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to allocate big data structures in the stack

Why? Why can't you simply use malloc/free?

> Can the problem depend on this?

Probably memory access in your `f2` is out of bounds and reaches up into the stack frame of `f1`. This is not directly related to the size of your stack, but you likely have an out-of-bounds array access there, with an index too large instead of writing to the array in `f2`'s stack frame you're trashing something in `f1`.

Had you used dynamic memory this problem would likely manifest itself as a segfault. I strongly suggest you switch to dynamic memory and use a memory debugger like Valgrind to track down the offending instruction in your code.

Comment: I used malloc and free in the beginning, but i have troubles if I do something like creating a function myFunc() that allocates, uses and deletes the data structeres and call this function in a loop (double free error and stuff like that).

Comment: A function that allocates/uses/destroys wouldn't have a double free error because of loops, just because of bugs.

Comment: @datenwolf: I used malloc/free for some structures and now it seems to work correctly. Thank you.